# Retrieve data package- and call statistics as background service

Tags: ios4

I have two questions?

1. Is it possible to retrieve voice call and data traffic statistics (like number of calls, call duration, data packages sent /recieved (kB) etc) using iPhone SDK 4?
2. Is it in some way possible to have an application as a background service and make use of local push notifications (alarm) in order to have the app retriving the call statistics at certain intervals (ie have it wake up and send data over internet)?

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You can't get voice call statistics at all, under iOS 4 or iOS 5.  These kinds of things would be a security and privacy risk in Apple's eyes and if you figured out a way to do it, that app would likely not be approved.

There *are* methods to get network usage statistics, but it might not be exactly the data you want.  For network statistics on the device, you can get per-interface stats via ["`getifaddrs`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) (man page linked for you).  You get the list of addresses on that system, and then for each AF_LINK address, cast the ifa_data field to a (const struct if_data *) and access the interface statistics from there.

(there are two caveats -- these stats are all reset to zero at startup time, and there's no easy way to easily tell which interface is cellular versus WiFi).